# Dapper query result to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have mapped my models and come up with the following code below. How to display the data as well the column names using datagridview?

```
public class DivisionModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DivisionModel Division { get; set; }
}

using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
{
    var sql = @"SELECT * FROM[Employee] em JOIN Division dv ON em.DivisionId = dv.id";
    var result = connection.Query<EmployeeModel, DivisionModel, EmployeeModel>(sql, (employee, division) => { employee.Division = division; return employee; });
    result.ToList().ForEach(employee => MessageBox.Show(($"FirstName: {employee.FirstName},MiddleName: {employee.MiddleName}, LastName: {employee.LastName},Division: {employee.Division.DivisionName}")));
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a datatable and then make the `datagridview1.DataSource = dt;`

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DivisionModel Division { get; set; }

    public DataTable MakeTable(List<EmployeeModel> model)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Employee Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Middle Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Division Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Division Name", typeof(string));

        foreach(EmployeeModel employee in model)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { employee.id, employee.FirstName, employee.MiddleName, employee.LastName, employee.Division.id, employee.Division.DivisionName });
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a `DataTable` here; most data bindings work just fine (better, even) with things like `List<T>`. So... why do this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, simply assigning the list as the data source should be sufficient, i.e.

```cs
var data = result.ToList();
// TODO: any debug code you want to inspect "data" here, as per your MessageBox.Show
yourGrid.DataSource = data;
```

Note: if you have a `BindingSource` configured against the `DataGridView`, then you'd update the `BindingSource`'s `DataSource` instead.

Comment: Your answer will not give a two dimensional table.  The OP has a parent class and the child class.

Comment: @jdweng then simply: flatten the model, if that is what OP wants to bind to

Comment: Most cases you can't flatten the model.  That is why my code works better than a straight bind.

Comment: @jdweng `class MyThingForBinding { public int EmployeeId {get;set;} ... public string DivisionName {get;set;} }` - done; heck, you could probably use `record`